# How to implement app indexing with library project?

Tags: android, android-library, android-app-indexing, google-app-indexing, firebase-app-indexing

I'm trying to implement app indexing for one of my apps, but I'm not quite sure what I should return as the `appUri` for the app indexing `Action`.

Let's say I have a the package name `com.example.myapp` and the `webUri` `http://example.com/some/path`.

As I understand it, the `appUri` would normally be `com.example.myapp/http/example.com/some/path` in this case, correct?

Now  enter the library project that my app uses, and where the indexed activity exists. Let's call the library project `com.example.mylibrary` and the indexed activity `MyActivity`.

If I want to start the activity using adb, I would use

`adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "http://example.com/some/path" com.example.myapp/com.example.mylibrary.MyActivity`

So, my question is - what should the `appUri` for the app indexing `Action` be in this case? Is it affected at all by the fact that the activity is within the library project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you can build Action by Action.Builder provided by library. As uri you need to provide related URI. So if you want to index View Action you should provide URI of product, that was viewed.

```
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
    String uriStr = builder
        .scheme("http")
        .authority("example.com")
        .appendPath("some/path").build().toString();

    Action action = new Action.Builder(Action.Builder.VIEW_ACTION)
        .setObject("productName", uriStr)
        .build();
```

For more details you can look at [logging actions docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/android/log-actions) and their sample app.

To test:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "{URL}" {package name}
```

where {package name} = com.example.myapp and URL = `http://example.com/some/path`

At the end, your Activity placed in library should have intent filter which can handle your URI `http://example.com/some/path`

Comment: Sorry, but your `adb` command doesn't work for me, I get a `Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent`. I believe this is because the activity is inside the library project, which is the reason I'm asking the question in the first place (see the `adb` command in the question - that's working since it references the library project)...

Comment: My bad - turns out the quotation marks around the URL had somehow got mangled into those fancy quotation marks (`“ ”`)! For some reason that caused `Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent` when only using the package name, but worked fine when specifying the full package name + activity. Problem solved.